# django form validation - compare inserted data

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

Question about forms and validation in Django, python.

I have a one field form, to where people can insert peoples names.
But it is needed that they can't enter names, which are not supported by a third party website.
My forms.py:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = MyModel
        fields = ('title', )


    def clean_title(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        # fields is the line, which checks from a 3rd party db , 
        #   if the name inserted is supported.
        # cleaned_data in the parentheses should be the name, inserted by the user.

        fields = client.search(cleaned_data).name

        # If the client returns the same name as the user has inserted, 
        #   the post must be valid.
        # If the user inserts name, which is not in the 3rd party db, 
        #   the client sends an error as a response and the post can't be accepted.

        if (self.cleaned_data.get('title') != fields)

            raise ValidationError(
                "This name is not supported"
            )

        return self.cleaned_data
```

I know, that code is a mess, it's because I've tried many different ways already.

I add views.py

```
def add_model(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        # commit=False means the form doesn't save at this time.
        # commit defaults to True which means it normally saves.
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
        model_instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/thanks')
else:
    form = MyModelForm()

return render(request, "polls/polls.html", {'form': form})
```

and models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"See nimi on juba lisatud."})
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

just in case, these are needed.

I hope, you understand, what I'm trying to achieve and maybe you can support me with some good tips or great example of code.
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field value in `clean_` method is available as `self.cleaned_data['field_name']`:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:    
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('title', )

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        try:
            name = client.search(title).name
        except HTTPError:
            raise ValidationError("Can't validate the name. Try again later")
        if title != name:
            raise ValidationError("This name is not supported")
        return title
```

Comment: This looks really good! But when running in localhost,it gives me an error like this:  
Exception Type: SyntaxError.  
Exception Value: invalid syntax (forms.py, line 20),  which is:   if (title != name).
Any ideas, where that came from? Could it be from my   name = client.search(title).name?

Comment: Sorry about that.  A forgot to add a colon after the `if` statement.  Answer fixed.

Comment: Whoops, I also didnt see it. Works like a charm, Thank you!

Comment: I know, you answered my question already, but if you have some time, I would ask another one.
 If the 3rd party db sends back HTTPError 404, the code doesnt raise ValidationError, like I thought it would. How to fix that?

Comment: How this 3rd party app reports 404 error?  Does it raise some sort of exception?

Comment: uhmm...yes, it's an exception. Exception Type: HTTPError. Exception Value: 
404 Client Error: Not Found.

Comment: Then wrap call to 3rd party app with `try`/`except` statement. See edited answer.